# Let unregistered users browse more than just "newest" questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, unregistered-users

When I browse questions on a site I'm registered for, I can see all questions - newest, featured, frequent, votes, active, and unanswered.
[image: Questions page of SO]

But on sites I am not registered for, I can browse only newest questions.
[image: Questions page of Academia]

Sometimes I just want to see the highest voted questions on a site, and not ask or answer any. I recall I used to be able to do this (every developer's least favourite phrase), am I imagining things?

Comment: Also see [Guest (not logged in) users can only sort questions with specific tag by newest](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242639)

Comment: (And I thought perhaps a re-close of the original report with [meta-tag:status-planned] would be helpful)