# Multiple tags search broken when searching as anonymous user?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search

When I input `[asdf][lisp]` into the search field on http://stackoverflow.com, without being logged in, only one tag remains. Is it broken?

Comment: Are the tags synonyms? Also - without knowing the tags an the site, we can't really investigate, can we?

Comment: I just tried it here, in the Meta search - no repro. Entered `[asd][asdf]`, both were used.

Comment: You put `[asdf]` as a tag?

Comment: Exactly as it is in the question.

Comment: Seems to work OK for me, both tags remain.

Comment: I entered `[asdf][lisp]` on [so] search. Still no repro. I see both tags. 20 questions tagged with both.

Comment: Try to log out and click stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asdf+lisp :)

Answer (score 7):

We only allow a single tag search for anonymous users at this time.

So yes, we will strip out the remaining tags when searching as anonymous.

Comment: What the heck??? 1) Why? 2) Why silently removing? I usually surf unlogged in.

Comment: It was a quick response to a DDOS attempt. We are still evaluating how to bring back this functionality.

Comment: Well, silently failing is definitively a bug.

Comment: Like I said, we were in a middle of a DDOS, not really a moment to write refined solutions.

Comment: Do you plan to remove this behaviour? If yes - when?

Comment: @Smit there is a fair chance this will become permanent, if the team will find out this is a risk to the whole system. I agree it should be better documented though. (e.g. a banner will appear when the system strips tags away)

Comment: So is this a dupe of this one? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242639/guest-not-logged-in-users-can-only-sort-questions-with-specific-tag-by-newest

Comment: @Oded has SE evaluated how to bring back this functionality yet? ;)

Comment: It is there for non anonymous users, @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ

Comment: @Oded you can't provide search links on other sites then - unloggen in users cannot use it. And still no error message.

Comment: Note that [this also happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266896/203101) when using `foo bar` instead of `[foo] [bar]` which is even more of a problem. I shouldn't run a tag search just because the word I entered happens to be a tag, and I certainly shouldn't have one of my search terms removed with no explanation. Especially when it works as expected on the actual search page. I understand this was to protect from a DDoS attack, but that shouldn't affect search terms that are not explicitly entered as tags but as regular strings.

Comment: This still happens. If you're not going to re-enable it for anonymous users, can you make a note on the search page when additional tags are stripped out?

Comment: @KevinMills it seems to work for anonymous users when you append "is:question" or "is:answer" to your query, so for example following query should return questions tagged with [tags] and [search] and [bug]:
`[tags][search][bug] is:question`

Comment: "at this time" - over two years later, is this about to  change? (if not, better remove this part)

Comment: @Sha - talking with the team to see if we can relax this or not.