# Multiple tag query only shows two tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-search

Am I able to use multiple or statements within my search query like:

[foo] or [foo1] or [foo2]

or use a wildcard like

[foo*]

When I try the above, it only returns two tags. Am I missing something?

Comment: Which tags are you using, exactly? And on what site?

Comment: I just tried it here and it works as expected: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion+or+bug+or+support

Comment: Which site is this on? I'm a bit hazy on the details, but IIRC Stack Overflow has some restrictions on searches by anonymous (and possibly low rep?) users because these tag lookups can get pretty expensive performance-wise.

Comment: @Oded do it in Private/Incognito/not logged in and you'll see what OP means.

Comment: Most likely part of the restrictions described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242639/guest-not-logged-in-users-can-only-sort-questions-with-specific-tag-by-newest), imposed after DDoS attack 2.5 years ago, and were never lifted since, fearing more attacks. At this point, I can say for sure those restrictions are now permanent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have some code that prevents *anonymous* users from issuing oversized tag queries, because in the past that has been used maliciously by issuing huge tag unions from botnets.

The code currently limits anonymous users to 3 tags in that UI; I'm open to increasing this - it is simply something that needs a little monitoring and thought. For example, I'm sure we could increase it to 5 without any huge concern, but *we'd need to monitor it*.

However! It looks like you're being *unduly* bitten by a small bug here; the code that applies this filter happens *before* the code that attempts to interpret the query, so "or" is being treated as a tag in this count. I will change the code to work correctly with combination markers.

This is *especially* awkward because it is only the "or" scenario that is a problem - when folks "and" tags (which is the default in some screens if no combination marker is present), it actually makes the query *cheaper* (usually, not quite always) - as it gives us more opportunity to pick the smallest set to work from. And if you ask for more than 5 tags in an "and", we know the answer immediately: nothing.

---

Edit: the bug re combinators being counted incorrectly is now resolved; links like [`discussion or bug or support`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion+or+bug+or+support) now work correctly. I'm going to mark this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), and consider the "should we allow *more* tags than 3 for anonymous" a separate discussion that is currently [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).